# How to pass command-line arguments to IntelliJ itself, to alter behavior of IDE (not my own app within IDE)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, command-line-arguments

I want to try using the new new Metal-based rendering pipeline on macOS for Java 17, as explained in [*JEP 382: New macOS Rendering Pipeline*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/382). The new feature is not enabled by default. To switch from the default ([*OpenGL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)) to the new feature ([*Metal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API))), one must supply the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) with command-line arguments upon launch:

```sh
-Dsun.java2d.metal=true
```

I would like try running IntelliJ under Metal rather than OpenGL. So I need to convince IntelliJ to (a) Use Java 17, and (b) pass that argument to the JVM driving its own operations.

I understand that IntelliJ runs on its own internally-bundled JVM rather than the JVM installed on my Mac. So:

- How do I know the version of the JVM being used by IntelliJ?
- Can I point IntelliJ towards another JVM for its own operations, for a later version of 17 (understanding that I am operating IntelliJ in an untested and unsupported environment)?
- How do I pass a command-line argument to that JVM when IntelliJ is launching?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate Edition) on macOS Big Sur on MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon (M1 chip).

---

I am *not* asking about how to pass command-line arguments to an app being developed within IntelliJ. So I am *not* asking about how to use the [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) feature of IntelliJ. That topic has been asked and answered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As an alternative, I would suggest [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) which is based on SWT that uses native widgets, not requiring such ugly hacks. [;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69367716/eclipse-2021-not-launching-on-mac-m1#comment122611247_69367716)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I know the version of the JVM being used by IntelliJ?

You can find that in the 'about' dialog:

[image: about dialog]

> Can I point IntelliJ towards another JVM for its own operations, for a later version of 17 (understanding that I am operating IntelliJ in an untested and unsupported environment)?

Technically you can, but it might cause problems in your IDE I think? There's a warning in their documentation, see [Change the boot Java runtime of the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) to switch to a custom JDK.

> How do I pass a command-line argument to that JVM when IntelliJ is launching?

Once your IDE is running, go to `Help > Edit Custom VM options`, see their [Advanced configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Your approach seems correct. But, for the record, IntelliJ 2021.3 EAP is *not* compatible with Java 17 as the JVM for its own internal operations. I got some errors related to failing to parse Java version number, and errors that result in being unable to quit IntelliJ. So I switched back to using the JVM bundled with IntelliJ.